# java.io.IOException: Running in secure mode, but config doesn't have a keytab

Tags: java, solr, cloudera-cdh

I config lily using cdh5 commandline. Follow the document at [search_config_hbase_indexer_for_search](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/search_config_hbase_indexer_for_search.html).

My config file is :

```
cat /etc/default/solr
SOLR_PORT=8983
SOLR_ADMIN_PORT=8984
SOLR_LOG=/var/log/solr
SOLR_ZK_ENSEMBLE=host-172-17-110-81:2181/solr
SOLR_HDFS_HOME=hdfs://hadoop-jkzl:8020/solr
SOLR_HDFS_CONFIG=/etc/hadoop/conf
SOLR_KERBEROS_ENABLED=true
SOLR_KERBEROS_KEYTAB=/etc/solr/conf/solr.keytab
SOLR_KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL=solr/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL
#SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE=simple
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE=kerberos
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_SIMPLE_ALLOW_ANON=true
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS_KEYTAB=/etc/solr/conf/solr.keytab
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL=HTTP/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS_NAME_RULES=DEFAULT
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_JAAS_CONF=/etc/solr/conf/jaas.conf

cat /etc/solr/conf/jaas.conf
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=false
  keyTab="/etc/solr/conf/solr.keytab"
  principal="solr/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL";
};

ls -l /etc/solr/conf/solr.keytab
-r--------. 1 solr hadoop 1642 Oct  8 07:50 /etc/solr/conf/solr.keytab

more hbase-indexer-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>   
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>   
<value>host-172-17-110-49,host-172-17-110-77,host-172-17-110-78</value> 
</property>
<property>   
<name>hbaseindexer.zookeeper.connectstring</name>   
<value>host-172-17-110-49,host-172-17-110-77,host-172-17-110-78:2181</value> 
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbaseindexer.authentication.type</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbaseindexer.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>/etc/hbase/conf/hbase.keytab</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbaseindexer.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>HTTP/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbaseindexer.authentication.kerberos.name.rules</name>
   <value>DEFAULT</value>
  </property>


</configuration>

more /etc/hbase-solr/conf/jaas.conf
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=false
  keyTab="/etc/hbase/conf/hbase.keytab"
  principal="hbase/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL";
 };

grep login hbase-indexer-env.sh
export HBASE_INDEXER_OPTS="$HBASE_INDEXER_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/hbase-solr/conf/jaas.conf"
```

but when i add-indexer ,hbase-solr's log error:

```
15/10/10 03:19:41    INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client
   connection,   
   connectString=host-172-17-110-77:2181,host-172-17-110-49:2181,host-172-17-110-78:2181
   sessionTimeout=90000   
   watcher=host-172-17-110-81,57865,14444471812720x0,   
   quorum=host-172-17-110-77:2181,host-172-17-110-49:2181,host-172-17-110-78:2181,
   baseZNode=/hbase 15/10/10 03:19:41 INFO client.ZooKeeperSaslClient:  
   Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism. 15/10/10 03:19:41 DEBUG   
   client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: creating sasl client:   
   client=hbase/host-172-17-110-81@JKZL;service=zookeeper;serviceHostname=host-172-17-110-49
   15/10/10 03:19:41 ERROR supervisor.IndexerSupervisor: Problem   
   starting indexer myIndexer java.io.IOException: Running in secure   
   mode, but config doesn't have a keytab
              at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:236)
              at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.login(User.java:383)
              at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.login(User.java:250)
              at com.ngdata.sep.impl.SepConsumer.<init>(SepConsumer.java:163)
              at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.supervisor.IndexerSupervisor.startIndexer(IndexerSupervisor.java:234)
              at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.supervisor.IndexerSupervisor.access$1000(IndexerSupervisor.java:78)
              at com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.supervisor.IndexerSupervisor$EventWorker.run(IndexerSupervisor.java:407)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How I can fix it the `error:config doesn't have a keytab`?